# Dojo get next sibling based on current event target

Tags: dojo, siblings

I have this dropdown [menu](http://jsfiddle.net/zV78L/77/), and all i want to do is upon firing the onmouseenter event, to change the border-left of the targets next sibling to white. So far i can address the currentTarget's border-left with ease, but i cant find a way to do the same for the next sibling. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try this

```
dojo.query(evt.currentTarget).next()[0]
```

Comment: thanks a lot dude it worked like a charm and works as a cross-browser solution. I just had to place a dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse"); at the top.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM node attribute `nextSibling` can be used to get the next sibling. See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling.

If you want to apply some filtering when getting next sibling, e.g. get the next sibling with a certain CSS class name, try to use `dojo.query`. For example,

```
dojo.query(node).siblings(".myClass")
```

returns a node list of siblings of `node` with class name `myClass`.

Comment: i think nextSibling might return textnode also. nextElementSibling will return the next sibling element node

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alex Cheng, although rajkamal is right, nextSibling does return textnode's which requires me to check for nodeTypes to get the correct element i'm after. nextElementSibling also works but it does not work in old versions of IE (< IE9). Your research was valuable to me thanks +1 for that.